# How can I read button action from an Adaptive Card in node.js?

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

If I have an adaptive card as follows :

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
.addAttachment({
    contentType: "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    content: {
        type: "AdaptiveCard",
        speak: "<s>Your  meeting about \"Adaptive Card design session\"<break strength='weak'/> is starting at 12:30pm</s><s>Do you want to snooze <break strength='weak'/> or do you want to send a late notification to the attendees?</s>",
           body: [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Adaptive Card design session",
                    "size": "large",
                    "weight": "bolder"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Conf Room 112/3377 (10)"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "12:30 PM - 1:30 PM"
                },
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Snooze for"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                    "id": "snooze",
                    "style":"compact",
                    "choices": [
                        {
                            "title": "5 minutes",
                            "value": "5",
                            "isSelected": true
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "15 minutes",
                            "value": "15"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "30 minutes",
                            "value": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Snooze"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "I'll be late"
                }
            ]
    }
});
```

How do I present it in the conversation, so that the bot waits for the user to click on one of the submit buttons?

And how do I read the button which has been pressed?

I couldn't find any example in node.js to do so.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `session.message.value` is present

```
if (session.message && session.message.value) {
 // process your card's submit action
}
```

Take a look at the following [Adaptive Card sample](https://github.com/southworkscom/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/node-adaptivecards/Node/cards-AdaptiveCards) to see how you to process submit actions.

Comment: Oh no! - link is giving a 404